# Is it SQL Injection Vuln?

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

Today my friend asking help to test and prevent his website from sql injection..

After i tried basic sql injection like `1 OR 1=1`, `' OR 1--'`,`' '1'='1` There is no mysql error displayed..

But After i tried `chr(0xbf) . chr(0x27) . ' OR username = username #'` on its username and password login form it showing error:

`Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

Is it can be vuln to inject with SQL Injection method?

Cause after i try with SQLMap it say does not seem to be injectable.

Comment: Am I taking it right that you were trying to inject a *PHP code*?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: What do you need chr(0xbf) and chr(0x27) for? Do you get any error if you don't concatenate those two characters with the SQL code?

Answer (score 1):

If a friend asks you to look into his site just tell him to hand you the code in question. It will be much easier to see than to test and a lot more reliable.

Comment: But i have to proof that error can be injectable.. I must have proof i can see its database..

Comment: Which will be a lot easier for you with a white-box approach. Take a look at the code in question, try to understand what happens with the payload you mentioned and debug it when sending your potentially malicious payload. Then you can still craft an exploit that alters the DB if your friend insists.